# Can I embed a windows 7 gadget into WPF application

Tags: wpf, windows-7, embed, windows-desktop-gadgets

I am thinking of embedding a Windows 7 gadget into a WPF application, as there are already so many Windows 7 gadgets available on the internet.

Windows 7 gadgets seems to be using Html, css and javascript. Thus, if I'm going to embed the gadget, I will need to have Webbrowser control (which has lots of memory problems and opacity etc.) which will make the application designer ugly.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is your requirement ? it looks like a bit weird, there is maybe other ways to reach your goal.

Comment: just a `WebBrowser` control won't help. The Sidebar provides custom APIs through javascript which just aren't there in a normal `WebBrowser` control.